# Using GIT Extension, how do I merge multiple commits on the server?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have multiple commits on the server, some redundant and I would like to squash them. I have found on stackoverflow how this is done through command line but not using Git Extension.

Comment: I know, this kind of comment might be annoying, but still: Is there a reason, why you can't just do it on the command line? Usually in git, it's easier for many things to execute them on the command line than in a GUI like Git Extensions. (Of course, it might still be of interest, how it would be done there.)

Comment: On another note: Your question is a bit short. Would you mind to elaborate more on what you want to achieve? As a start, you could add the supposed solution for the command line which you found.

Comment: Thanks Don, the comment wasn't annoying. As I am new to GIT and GIT Extension. I preferred the GUI if the functionality for squashing existed. As a beginner I find the command line a bit intimidating but I will try using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be misunderstanding the article you found: With git, you *always* work locally, and push the result to a server. If what you did changes history (e.g. squashing), you'd have to `git push --force`.

Git relies on this strict separation of a remote being *just a shared storage* that it's important to understand that you do nothing *on* the server, but everything in your local clone of the repository, pushing the changes *to* the server.

In effect, you will have to squash locally using your GUI, and then push it to your remote repository.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this. I am new to version control and began with learning through GIT extension.

Comment: that's fine! I do recommend https://try.github.io/ for complete beginners, and http://git-scm.com/documentation as soon as the basics are clear.